# Ignore element appearance order in extension from base type

Tags: xml, xsd

In an XSD, I have a ReturnType which is extended from base SaleType. I don't care about the order in which the elements appear in the xml.

I can change the XSD but I can't change the way the xml is written. For some reason the way xml is written is not in a sequential order as defined in the XSD. I could make the order not matter in base type but in the extension. How do I fix this?

```
<xs:complexType name="SaleType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"> <!--adding this ignores the order for Sale but does not enforce it to the extensions-->
            <xs:element name="ItemID" type="xs:string" />
            xs:element name="Description" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="ReturnType">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="SaleType">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Reason" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>

<!--Even though Description appears before ItemID, this xml validates since Reason is at the end-->
<Return>
    <Description>Item 123</Description>
    <ItemID>123</ItemID>
    <Reason>R1</Reason>
</Return>    

<!--This xml does not validate since Reason is at the beginning-->
<Return>
    <Reason></Reason>
    <Description>Item 123</Description>
    <ItemID>123</ItemID>
</Return>
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use ***extension*** in XSD to override an order specified by a sequence.  See instead ***[override](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#override-schema)*** if you cannot change the base class directly, but note that `xs:override` requires XSD 1.1.